# Passing char vector and string vector to a function

Tags: c++, function

How do I do:

```
void writeFiledata(vector<char> tttstatus, vector<string> iflines)
{

}

int main()
{
writeFiledata(vector<char> tttstatus, vector<string> iflines);
return 0;
}
```

I can pass two ints to a function, and I can pass a 3D vector to a function, but I can't pass two 1D vectors?

Comment: Given variables of the proper types, there's no difference passing an int vs. a vector vs. two vectors. For whatever reason, you have types (as in declaration syntax) in your argument expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either pass your variable or pass reference. While passing as varaible, your function going to create a local copy of your variables inside your function and impacts may not reflect in calling function(in you case main) after the function call, since you are not returning anything in your function writeFiledata function. So in corrected code below, I opted option to pass variable as reference.

```
void writeFiledata(vector<char> & tttstatus, vector<string>& iflines)
{

}

int main()
{
 vector<char> tttstatus;
 vector<string> iflines;
//fill vectors using std::vector::push_Back

writeFiledata( tttstatus,  iflines);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: ohh duh oops thanks, guess it's time for me to go to sleep

Comment: `const vector<char>&` and `const vector<string>& iflines` is more typical if you aren't going to modify the data.